# Is there a way to specify a return address in MIPS without using jal?

Tags: assembly, mips

I would like the PC to return to where it is in my program after a **conditional branch, not a jump and link.**

I would like to set return address without using `jal` and instruct the program counter to return there.

What is the best way to do this?

thank you, Matthew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jal` computes the return address and places it a register; you could write code to do the same.  But I think you'll find using a conditional branch to decide whether or not to execute a `jal` is the better way to go.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of it that way. I'll give that a try.